# SOAP with Retrofit2 Order issue

Tags: java, android, soap, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to use retrofit to make SOAP request. Everything is working fine except sorting / order of the elements.

Here's my POJO code

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace;
import org.simpleframework.xml.NamespaceList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Order;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

/**
 * Created by ankit on 13/01/17.
 */

@Root(name = "soapenv:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "type", reference = "http://tempuri.org/type")
})

public class SoapLoginReq {

    @Element(name = "soapenv:Body")
    private SoapBodyReq soapBodyReq;

    public SoapLoginReq(String username, String password){
        soapBodyReq = new SoapBodyReq(new Logon(username, password));
    }

    public SoapBodyReq getSoapBodyReq() {
        return soapBodyReq;
    }

    public void setSoapBodyReq(SoapBodyReq soapBodyReq) {
        this.soapBodyReq = soapBodyReq;
    }

    static class SoapBodyReq{

        @Element(name = "type:logon")
        private Logon logon;

        public SoapBodyReq(Logon logon){
            this.logon = logon;
        }

        public Logon getLogon() {
            return logon;
        }

        void setLogon(Logon logon) {
            this.logon = logon;
        }
    }

    @Order(elements = {"type:password", "type:username"})
    static class Logon{
        @Element(name = "type:username")
        private String username;

        @Element(name = "type:password")
        private String password;

        public Logon(String username, String password){
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have added @Order on Logon class. But I am getting following error when I try to run this.

`Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Ordered element 'type:password' missing for class test.SoapLoginReq$Logon`.

I am trying to make it for the first time, I tried putting string name in order element array. Like `@Order(elements = {"password", "type:username"})` instead of `type:password`

Still it won't work.

Here's my Activity Code.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();


Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer))
        .baseUrl("https://requestb.in/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();

WWIFaces wwiFaces = retrofit.create(WWIFaces.class);

wwiFaces.logon(new SoapLoginReq("ankit", "pise")).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

I have worked on REST earlier but SOAP is new for me and it seems Order is very essential in requests.

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**

When I added `@Order(elements = {"type:username", "type:password"})` To the parent element i.e. Logon

```
static class SoapBodyReq{

        @Element(name = "type:logon")
        @Order(elements = {"type:username", "type:password"})
        private Logon logon;

        public SoapBodyReq(Logon logon){
            this.logon = logon;
        }

        public Logon getLogon() {
            return logon;
        }

        void setLogon(Logon logon) {
            this.logon = logon;
        }
    }
```

It did not throw the error. But sorting is still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, `@Order` never works with namespace prefixes involved. Remove them all and @Order should work.

If you need namespace prefixes, by default SimpleXML organizes elements in alphabetic order (using the *variable name* instead of the `@Element` name tag), so the only option is name the variables in an alphabetic order you want. Prefixing 'a' to username in this case should put the `type:username` first.

```
static class Logon{
    @Element(name = "type:username")
    private String aUsername;

    @Element(name = "type:password")
    private String password;

    public Logon(String username, String password){
        this.aUsername= username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return aUsername;
    }

    void setUsername(String username) {
        this.aUsername = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just received notification for this question,

heres how I resolved this one.

```
static class SoapBodyReq{

    @Element(name = "type:logon")
    @Order(elements = {"type:username", "type:password"})
    private Logon logon;

    public SoapBodyReq(Logon logon){
        this.logon = logon;
    }

    public Logon getLogon() {
        return logon;
    }

    void setLogon(Logon logon) {
        this.logon = logon;
    }
}
```

Instead of this I renamed elements to sort in alphabetic orders like below

```
static class Logon{
    @Element(name = "type:username")
    private String element1_username;

    @Element(name = "type:password")
    private String element2_password;

    public Logon(String username, String password){
        this.element1_username = username;
        this.element2_password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return element1_username;
    }

    void setUsername(String username) {
        this.element1_username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return element2_password;
    }

    void setPassword(String password) {
        this.element2_password = password;
    }
}
```

Cheers!